# MS Teams SIP gateway - preview programme or specification?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Does anyone know of any resources for information / specifications / preview access to the MS Teams SIP Gateway that was the subject of a further announcement last week?
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/introducing-operator-connect-and-more-teams-calling-updates/ba-p/2176398
There was some information previously regarding certification programmes ... (the link implies just S4B, but it covers Teams too).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SkypeForBusiness/certification/how-to-join
But this appears to be closed.

Thanks
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

we have observed the same question raised by you through email, concerned team member will respond to you sure. For now we are closing this question as duplicate.